# unpacking Yesod Scaffolded types

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod, ghci

One of my favorite things to do when working on a haskell program is to use the ghci :t  and :info commands to figure out type mistakes in a program.

I can use this when I run toy programs in yesod but I can't figure out how to do it with the full on scaffolded site. If this is the wrong way to be going about it I understand and am open to better methodological suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Well this was actually pretty easy and I feel silly now.

Get the package cabal-ghci then load Foundation and Application and done.